# When to NOT use an interface as a return type?

Tags: c#

I've read it's generally a good idea to use interfaces as return types to reduce coupling.  When is it a BAD idea to use an interface as a return type

Comment: This is vague enough to be impossible to answer in a general way. Design decisions at this level of detail are highly specific to the use case and context.

Answer (score 5):

There are two general cases when you shouldn't use an interface as a return type:

- When your callers need functionality of the class that is *not* also available through an interface, and
- When your class is part of a framework that puts additional requirements on returning interfaces (e.g. classes used with WCF).

In all cases when you can use an interface as a return type it is a good idea to use one.

Comment: Sorry for this generality, but this is exactly the type of answer that I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Another example is when you want to return something that the caller *knows* must be immutable - you need to return an immutable concrete class for that. An interface could be implemented by a mutable class, so it doesn't provide such a guarantee.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's certainly true. One pattern that I used in situations like that was making an immutable interface, and then deriving mutable interface from it. This allowed me to return an interface for both mutable and immutable objects, depending on the situation.